# When Creating VM in Azure 'Select Size' is Greyed Out

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure and started a new free trial account. As one of the first things to try, I decided to create a VM. As I followed steps in Azure portal, I was stuck when it came to 'Select Size', because all of them are greyed out; and per my understanding, the field is required.

I was using the default region (USEast), and I selected no AZ and 'Ubuntu 18.04 LTS' as the image the VM is based upon.

I googled this issue on the internet. And I have done the following to rectify the issue but no luck:

- switched to use different PC with different IP (as some suggested)
- "clear All filter' in Select Size window and specified VM size
- selected different VM images
- ensured there is a credit attached to my subscription (as some suggested)
- ensured there is no resources created to avoid hit the quotas (as some suggested)

This is something very basic, and it should've worked out-of-the-box. I am disappointed with the experience. But I want to give it the benefit of doubt and will continue to try out Azure if this issue is resolved. Maybe something very simple that I might've missed on my side.

Thank you so much for the help in advance.

Comment: Try to change region, Recently Azure usage increased 775% and because of that many user-reported issues like not able to spine up new VM or not able to change size. I read somewhere Microsoft put some limitation on free credit and region.

Comment: @Pankaj, Good advice. I flipped through almost all US regions available to me, finally US West works for me this time. It am able to successfully create a VM for the first time. I will mark your answer as the solution if you create an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to COVID-19 most of the enterprise user working from home and the usage of Azure and Microsoft service has increased a lot. Microsoft says that there has been a colossal [775 percent increase in usage of its cloud services](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2020/03/29/microsoft_azure_usage_surge_coronavirus/).

> All that Azure usage appears to have led to users in many regions "observing deployments for some compute resource types in these regions drop below our typical 99.99 per cent success rates". Which goes a long way towards explaining the inability to create resources as The Register revealed last week.
>
> Concurrently, we monitor support requests and, if needed, encourage customers to consider alternative regions or alternative resource types, depending on their timeline and requirements.

Try to change your deployment region.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the VM's we are unable to create. This is due to heavy toll on the resources.
You can read more here : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/our-commitment-to-customers-and-microsoft-cloud-services-continuity/

For time being seems like we have to opt for some other size.

Comment: thank you for the reply. yes, I was able to fix the issue by exhausting the US regions they have. painful, but at least worked.