# Can't able to purchase GPU based VMs in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, cloud, azure-vm-scale-set

Though I have upgraded my free trial account to pay-as-you-go subscription i can't able to purchase the GPU based VMs. i can't able to select those machines also, it shows a message like

> Size not available
>
> This Size  is currently unavailable in this subscription:
>
> NotAvailableForSubscription.

i choose the region:Central-India where NV_6 series gpu is available. but it shows not available

[first image choosen Region:Central india](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaieK.png)

So, i choose other countries like East-US etc... but it shows the same message again.

[second image choosen Region:East-US](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lb01B.png)

and i am in the Default directory is that could be a problem? or what i have to do please help me with this i am literally stuck with this.

Comment: I think this is the issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/61093822/4140278

Comment: You can also raise a support ticket from Azure Portal for confirmation on this issue

Comment: You need to make sure if your subscription supports the VM size as the error shown.

Comment: Thank you @PankajRawat for the information may be this is the reason it seems,